# fixing null pointer error

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, jframe, jpanel, superclass

I am getting a null pointer from inside a class that has another class extending it. The class extending it has a `super` line and this line is causing it to be set to null...

Class with the null error (Launcher):

```
private Frame frame;

public Launcher(Frame frame, int id) {
    this.frame = frame;
```

line that gets the error (in Launcher):

```
frame.ThreeD(); //THIS IS LINE 77
```

In the Frame class

```
public void ThreeDLauncher() {      
    new Launcher(this, 0);
}
```

---

and here is another class that is creating the null:

```
public class Options extends Launcher {

public Options() {
    super(null, 1);
}
```

so i need to re-arrange it so it no longer creates this null but it won't let me have nothing there? It also can't change whats set in the Launcher class.

How can i fix this?

**UPDATE**
this is the error in detail:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ThreeD.Launcher$1.actionPerformed(Launcher.java:77)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2028)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2351)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:387)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:242)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:236)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6373)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3267)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6138)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2085)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4735)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2143)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4565)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4621)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4282)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4212)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2129)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2478)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4565)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:679)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:85)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:638)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:636)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:98)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:652)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:650)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:649)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:296)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:196)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:188)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

Comment: What's the full stack trace of your `NullPointerException`?

Comment: For some questions, code fragments are not enough to provide a valid judgement call. And seems like this is exactly that situation, Please do provide the complete code and as mentioned by @Jeffrey , THE STACK TRACE :-) Where is your `Launcher Class's Line 77` ?

Comment: Can you change modify the `Launcher` code?

Comment: So where is your ActionListener code? I have to wonder if you're using inheritance correctly and for the right purpose. I have to wonder if your program design is in error. Regardless, I don't think that you've provided enough information to allow this question to be answered yet.

Comment: What do you mean by "won't let me have nothing there?" You pass a `Frame` -- and what exactly happens? That `Launcher` class is clearly useless without a `Frame` so I don't know how you expect it to work without one.

Comment: we need some missing code here so that we can see what is wrong

Comment: It appears he's solved it, but I still have a hunch that the code design is off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a non-null `Frame` is essential.  Therefore, the `Options` classes constructor needs to supply a frame.  Maybe something like this:

```
public class Options extends Launcher {
    public Options(Frame frame) {
        super(frame, 1);
    }
    ...
```

Comment: You have to supply a non-null `Frame` argument when you call the `Options` constructor ... of course.

Answer (score 0):

Launcher needs another constructor that does not need Frame passed in.

```
Public Launcher(int id) {
   this.frame = new Frame();
   this.id = id;
}
```

That may be where the null is coming from.